# Speech Recognition in UWP not works in background

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, win-universal-app

I would like if Speech Recognition in UWP would recognize even if application is not active.

I have these settings currently:

```
async void InitializeSpeechRecognizer()
    {
        SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer();
        speechRecognizer.StateChanged += HandleSpeech_State;
        speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.ResultGenerated += HandleSpeech;

        StorageFile grammar = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"Grammar.xml"); // file

        SpeechRecognitionGrammarFileConstraint grammarContraint = new SpeechRecognitionGrammarFileConstraint(grammar);
        speechRecognizer.Constraints.Add(grammarContraint);

        SpeechRecognitionCompilationResult compilantResult = await speechRecognizer.CompileConstraintsAsync(); // compile grammar

        if (compilantResult.Status == SpeechRecognitionResultStatus.Success)
            await speechRecognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.StartAsync();
    }
```

InitializeSpeechRecognizer is called in MainPage

When I activate app I can see in debug window state changes. After I activate another app nothings happen :(

Thanks for any idea!

Answer (score -1):

you have to use a BackgroundWorker thread for your application to work while not in focus.

backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(testFunction);

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: This is for .Net Silverlight while he is developing an UWP app, background task is used in an UWP app. See [Support your app with background tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt299103.aspx). And I don't even think a background task of UWP app can solve this problem here.